# Finding the latest updated value with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys i have a table structure like

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5),
 VALUES (2,'blah',3,31,51);
```

Suppose i have updated my table like

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET NAME = 'anewname'
WHERE AGE = 3;
```

So what i need is that i just need a query to find the last updated value ie 3

I have tried triggers and have tried using `LAST_INSERTED_ID()` .I have also used `TIMESTAMP` but i could get the value 3.

PS ..I dont want to use select statement here to find the value 3.

Thanks

Comment: `I dont want to use select statement here to find the value 3`, .... why?

Comment: @ekad cuz i want to know is there any funtion to find the latest updated value

Comment: You love mysql and do not know how to select it? Its simple dude,

`SELECT age FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE id= YOUR_LAST_INSERTED_ID`

Comment: The update could have affected hundreds of rows. There won't be a single updated value.

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ see i just want to know is there any way to do this without selecting like doing it with any built in func

Comment: no, there are no function like this. But you need to rethink your design, if you want to earn something like this. But you can see a post about this here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,390616,390619

Comment: if there is an AUTO_INCREMENT in your table



SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'CUSTOMERS'

Comment: @Tejesh can you please post an example code

Comment: The way to ask sql engine for any data from your table is `SELECT`. You can create and call a stored proc/func, but they also have to `SELECT` the data for you. See chiastic-security's answer, its a good sollution. As an alternative, you can try create a trigger that stores the last update info in different table, but at the end you still have to `SELECT` from that table.

Comment: @MIvanIsten see i have used function actually but i didnt worked ,can you please provide a sample code ,,so that i can understand

Comment: I cant provide an example as INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES will not be present over there. Can you please try it out the same query replacing your database and table name

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to add a field `updatetime` with type `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

That way, the field will get updated automatically for you, and you can pull out the row with the most recently updated timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY updatetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Note that if you update lots of rows together then this will give you an arbitrary row, but it sounds as though that's what you want, since you're looking for a single row.

Your table now becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2), 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   updatetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Whenever you insert or update, the `updatetime` entry for the row will be updated automatically.

Your `INSERT` stays exactly the same:

```
INSERT INTO  CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)  
    VALUES (1,'aff',2,3,5),
    VALUES (2,'blah',3,31,51);
```

Note that I'm not specifying any value for `updatetime` here: it'll get populated automatically by the database. Same with an `UPDATE`.

Comment: can you please post an sql fiddle example

Comment: @lovemysql I've added the complete `CREATE` command for you. I've given you the complete code in the answer now, for creating the table and for finding the right row.

Comment: what would be the insert values actually ??..can you please provide it too .do i wanna add any value to updatetime

Comment: @lovemysql That's the point: you don't need to add any value for `updatetime`. You ignore that field when you add, and it will get populated for you. Your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands stay exactly the same.

Comment: can you please edit the answer with the insert value

Comment: @lovemysql I've done so, but it's exactly the same as you have already!

Comment: see as i told i just only need the updated value..ie anewname

Comment: @lovemysql did you add the new field into your table? Either manually, or by deleting the table and creating with the new code I gave you?

Comment: see i have updated the name to a value 'anewname' but the query you gave me didnt show output as anewname

Comment: please help me with this issue ..please provide an sql fiddle sample..i have updated the column but the query you gave me didnt output the updated value